# Is it possible to SSH to the Pi if the Pi is on an Ethernet cable to the router, and the laptop has a Wi-Fi connection?

Tags: pi-3, wifi, ssh, ethernet

I have a strange situation, my Pi is connected via an Ethernet wall port to my university's internet, and my laptop is connected to the internet via Wi-Fi.

It's set up this way because when the Pi was connected via Wi-Fi the connection kept dropping. But when I switched it to the Ethernet cable, my SSH won't connect. VNC connection still works, however.

Does anyone know why, or how to fix it?

Comment: Please post what `ifconfig` shows on the Pi and also what your laptop's IP address and subnet mask are.

Comment: It's possible that the wired and wireless networks are on different subnets. As @HeatfanJohn said, more info is necessary. If they are on separate subnets, it's very possible that your school has SSH blocked on a firewall between the differing networks.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation to you, mine works though I'm on a home network. I got around it by using an IP scanner to find the IP address of my Raspberry Pi (it's connected by ethernet to my router at home) and from there I used Putty as an SSH client to connect to it.

Comment: The OP said "VNC connection still works, however". This means the problem is not related to not knowing the IP address.

Comment: Ah fair enough, probably best if you see what other people say - I definitely don't know enough to help you out. Hope someone else can help you fix this situation :)